# Action POST/GET in form submitting

Tags: forms, http, post, get

> `GET` is used to retrieve remote data, and `POST` is used to insert/update remote data

But when we use `<form>` to send data we can put in `action` either POST or GET and in both cases data will be sent. In this case data will not be retrieved or inserted just will be sent to the server. 
Do these GET and POST methods in the `<form>` are not the same as GET and POST from the description above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form action will tell your browser how to send the form data.

In case of GEt the form data will be present as query string arguments, in case of POST as a `multipart/form-data` body. And, of course, this will also alter the method of the query (as `GET` or `POST`).

This is for the **client** part of the protocol.

Now, on the **server side**, `GET` and `POST` **SHOULD** not behave in the same way.

- `GET` is indempotent
- `POST` is not

It means the server (or the server chain, you could have a Reverse Proxy Cache in the chain) **MUST** expect that a POST is doing something to the application data, so the application or state is not the same after the POST (maybe you now have a session, or you've just deleted something, or added something). End this means **you cannot re-play a POST two times without risks**. In fact nobody should never replay the POST, that's one action.

If your form is posted as a `GET` that's a diffrent story. Your just asking for an url (wich contains your form data in the query string of the url), and you get a result, but replaying the same url several times **SHOULD NOT** be a problem, we could also cache the result and reuse this cached result for someone requesting the same url (so having the same elements in the form, which are now in the url).

So your application **MUST NOT** perform data alteration if the method is GET. Not deleting something, not creating something, etc.

So why would you send a form as GET? Maybe just to obtain a filtered page result where everybody should obtain the same page result with the same filters. But certainly not to post a registration form (or an admin-level-delete-this-user action).

Comment: Thank you for this response. As I understood GET is used not to update or write data but just does something like filtering (getting some data).